# Handle HTTP Errors with HTTPErrorResponse - component or service?

Tags: angular, error-handling

In Angular there is a common way to handle http errors by using HttpErrorResponse as I saw? Is this true ?

Second thing I'm wondering is where should I use this, in a service where I'm making API calls or in a component where I'm calling a service?

> Error handling in a component:

[image]

> Error handling in a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  getArticles(): Observable<People[]> {
    return this._http.get<People>(this.apiUrl + '/People/GetAll')
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }
```

So I'm wondering which of these ways are better, and more convention by following Angular documentation?

And why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Angular there is a common way to handle http errors by using HttpErrorResponse

**→ yes and no.**

This is common, but it isn't the best practice.

The best practice is to use an [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) like so :

```
export class ErrorHandlerService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
      .handle(req)
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {...});
  }

}
```

As for the location of your function, using an interceptor resolves this issue, but le me remind you of the best practice :

**→ You should keep the template related logic into your component, and the business related logic in your service.**

I don't remember exactly where it is stated in the documentation, but I am 100% sure of that. **EDIT** [**Here it is.**](https://angular.io/guide/architecture)

Comment: so basically in the component I should use an HttpErrorResponse, and not in a service ?

Comment: Yes I red your answer, I dont want to use interceptor at this moment I was looking for answer on my question, and I can not see where did you say / answer on my question, you said "You should keep the template related logic into your component, and the business related logic in your service."  what that has common with my question? bussiness related logic is I guess fetching data from database, and it's defined in service but what about error handling? service or component itself?

Comment: If you don't want to use interceptors then use your way, but do it in a service : http calls are business logic. Clicking on a button is template related. To picture that : imagine you use firebase for your backend, and your error message says that it's a firebase error. If you switch to Cassandra, you will have to change the error message as well. That's business. If you want to change the log out icon, you switch from bootstrap to font awesome. That's template logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the errors in global error handler with Angular ErrorHandler https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

Create a new class which implements ErrorHandler and handle error there. I am using this approach in production. In this way set error message and throw the error and it will hit global error handler. where you can notify the user with any notification service(ex: Toastr). Also, log the error if you want. You don't have to repeatedly write the same code in whole application several times.